# Visual Studio project built with cmake displays "File Modification Detected"

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

The Visual Studio 2019 project, which was built via cmake displays

> File Modification Detected
>
> The project ABC has been modified outside the environment
>
> Reload ... Ignore ...

message.

How can I prevent cmake from updating the VS config files, for the project or system wide?

In what section of the cmake build files this behavior is defined (so that I can rebuild the project without this feature)?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot prevent this (afaik). Consider the scenario where you add a source file to a target in a `CMakeLists.txt` file. CMake needs to update the Visual Studio project files it generated which results in project file(s) being overwritten. CMake sets up the solution in a way to ensure such an update on a modification of the cmake files. Visual Studio reacts to the solution/project files being overwritten by displaying the dialog you mentioned.

In general you'll want to click "Reload" which should just update the projects according to the modification in the cmake sources. If for a command line build tool shows up though, you may want to select "Ignore" though, since sometimes the build output is deleted on a reload of projects/the solution and you'll probably want to check the error message.

If you're interested: Overriding the project files happens in the ZERO_CHECK target.

If the dialog is displayed on a build even if you did not modify the cmake files since the last build, you may want to check the console for a warning in the output of cmake though; this may indicate that there may be some issue in your cmake files...